# How can I call the same pseudorandom number for a given i and j?

Tags: algorithm, random, language-agnostic

I'm working on a project with multiple functions. I call a pseudorandom number several times, each in different functions, and then do some math on it. For example:

```
f(i,j)*random(i,j)
```

I assume that in the different functions the pseudorandom number isn't equal to the pseudorandom number in another function at a given i and j. Is that a correct assumption? If so, how is it possible to change that?

If it matters, the language I'm using is Xojo, which is similar to VB6.

Comment: What is `random(i,j)`?

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth It's a pseudorandom number taken at a given i and j.

Comment: What do you mean by "at" a given i and j? Between those numbers? Or are i and/or j the seed?

Comment: @user2561523: Can you clarify exactly what your question is. I thought I understood but now am not so sure. What is `random(i,j)` exactly. Is it supposed to return the same random number every time it's called with a certain pair `i,j`. Is it supposed to generate a random number in the range `[i,j]`??

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking here either. Do you actually want random numbers at all, or do you want something like a well-distributed hash function of (i,j)?

Comment: Why don't you just call `random` once, and store the result in an intermediate variable?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not really sure what the question is, but hopefully giving some basics of pseudo-random number generators (PRNG) will answer it:

- This is more of a language feature, but usually calling the same function (i.e. `random`) is independent of where you call it from (there may be other determining factors).
- `random(i,j)` may or may not return the same number twice in a row or after some time. It's (pseudo-)random, we just don't know whether it will.

  If you want `random(i,j)` to **always** return the same value, you can consider writing your own function that maps some value of `i` and `j` to another value using some formula, or you can store all previous generated numbers in a `map`, and simply return this value if it exists.

  If you want `random(i,j)` to **never** return the same value, consider generating numbers from `i` to `j` and [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm) them and simply returning the next value in the list repeatedly.
- You can usually **set the seed** of a PRNG. This will cause that, if you get some sequence after setting the seed to some value, you will get the same sequence if you set the seed to the same value at some other time. This doesn't really serve much of a practical purpose (that I can think of) beyond giving you the capability to reproducible previous results exactly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `random(i,j)` to return the same random number each time it's called with the same `i,j` you could simply save the state.

One approach would be to store the state in an `n x n` matrix `R` (where `n` is the range of `i,j`). On the first call to `random(i,j)` set `R(i,j) = rand()`. On subsequent calls retrieve the existing value.

If the range of `i,j` is very large and the values sparse use a hash table for `R` instead of a matrix.